# Submitting a form using facebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, facebox

I'm using facebox to load pages into a DIV. Let's say one of these pages has a form that needs to be submitted, how can I set the action="" to both the page and to have it load into facebox?

Comment: Is this question still active? Do you still want this answered?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you want to achieve the following: submitting form doesn't reload the whole page, but only contents of facebox. Consider using [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) instead of div inside your facebox.